# Remove dash from string on back or delete key?

Tags: java, android

I have code that adds a dash after 5th and 12th digit but on deleting these digits, the dash is not getting deleted after pressing the backspace key.
It gets stuck after deleting the last digit.

this is the code which I implemented from one of stack link.

```
EditText Cnic;
int maxLength = 15;
int len =0;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

 Cnic = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.cnic_edtext);

    Cnic.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {new InputFilter.LengthFilter(maxLength)});
    Cnic.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            String str =  s.toString();
            if(s.length() == 5 || s.length() == 13){

                str += "-";
                Cnic.setText(str);
                Cnic.setSelection(str.length());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            String str =  s.toString();
            len = str.length();
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: Have you viewed my answer? Did it work?

Comment: no it does not works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it using a library `import tw.henrychuang.lib.AutoAddTextWatcher;`

```
 EditText Cnic;
int maxLength = 15;
String str;
Button save;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

 Cnic = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.cnic_edtext);
 save = (Button)findViewById(R.id.save_btn);
    Cnic.setFilters(new InputFilter[] {new InputFilter.LengthFilter(maxLength)});
    Cnic.setKeyListener(new DigitsKeyListener().getInstance("0123456789-"));


    Cnic.addTextChangedListener(new AutoAddTextWatcher(Cnic,
            "-",
            5, 12));


    save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
             str =  Cnic.getText().toString();

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Cnic "+str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });



}
```

Answer (score 0):

I remember trying to do something similar to this a while ago. What you would have to do first is check that **the change made to the text was a deletion.** You also have to set the EditText's text to a **substring of what was originally in there**, this way the '-' is not part of it. I've made changes to your code below.

Check my code below and if you have any further questions, just comment below.

```
int length = 0;
@Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        length = Cnic.getText().toString().length();
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        int new_length = Cnic.getText().toString().length();
        //The length has decreased, meaning that something was deleted. 
        if(length > new_length){
            String str =  s.toString();
            if(s.length() == 5 || s.length() == 13){
                //This sets the text to what was in the EditText, except it excludes the '-'
                Cnic.setText(str.subString(0, s.length()-2));
                Cnic.setSelection(str.length());
            }
        }else{
            //The action that  happened was not a delete, so just add the dashes to the text. 
            String str =  s.toString();
            if(s.length() == 5 || s.length() == 13){

                str += "-";
                Cnic.setText(str);
                Cnic.setSelection(str.length());
            }
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        String str =  s.toString();
        len = str.length();
    }
```

If this doesn't work, try putting the code from onTextChanged into afterTextChanged and see if that works. I think this answer should work.